# AtomicInteger in threadDefaultFactory

Tags: java, multithreading

Why there is an **AtomicInteger** in **DefaultThreadFactory**

```
private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
```

Just because it increments and store value or some other reason as well?

Answer (score 1):

Because it can be incremented atomically.

Incrementing an `AtomicInteger` consists of three actions:

1. Reading out the current value
2. Incrementing that value
3. Storing the incremented value

These three actions are executed as one atomic operation.

This means that another thread will not be able to intervene, e.g. between step 1 and 2 or between step 2 and 3 and corrupt the count. This behavior makes `AtomicInteger` safe for use in multi-threaded environments.

Comment: If i have ThreadPoolExecutor in which i will be giving my custom ThreadFactory i should use AtomicInteger or not? Increment it automatically is fine but is there any other reason?/

Comment: Atomically, not automatically.

Comment: Why actually the ThreadFactory will be contaminated when the new thread creation is done by a single thread? I mean the count. We can store it's previous value and increment it

Comment: There is no guarantee that the thread creation will be done by a single thread.

Comment: From which piece of code or document we know like the thread creation from JVM will be done by multithread? Can you please point me ?

Comment: You're able to obtain a reference to a `DefaultThreadFactory` object, right? How you use that object after that is completely up to you, no? You can spam a hundred threads that all use the same `DefaultThreadFactory` object to create even more threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125485/discussion-between-kulbhushan-singh-and-robby-cornelissen).

Answer (score 0):

That static value is incremented in constructor of DefaultThreadFactory. User can create an instance of factory in different threads and that incrementation could possible be losted, so AtomicInteger makes such approach thread-safe.